# Using TEXT() to look like "Accounting" format

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting

I'm trying to add an asterisk to a cell, so I can make a note below for the end user.  However, I'd like the cell to look like "Accounting" format.

Using `=TEXT(1000,"$#,###.00")&"*"` doesn't quite do the trick, as the currency symbol aligns directly before the first number.

Is there a way to format like Accounting, and still allow me to include my `*`?

Here's what it currently looks like:
[image]

and here's a mock-up of what I'd like to do:

[image]

Yes, I could to `=TEXT(1000,"$[bunch of spaces]#,###.00")` but that feels kludgy and won't necessarily expand with the number/column.

(Or is there some simple alternative I'm not thinking of? No VBA please, if it has to be VBA I'll simply put the `*` in a cell next to the number.)

Comment: Rather than using a formula to get formatting, use a custom cell format, something like: `_-$* #,##0.00_-"*";-$* #,##0.00_-"*";_-$* "-"??_-"*";_-@_-` should do the trick

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - A slight tweak was needed, but this works: `_($* #,##0.00"*"_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* "-"??_);_(@_)`. (Feel free to make that an Answer :D )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a formula to get formatting, use a custom cell format:

Bruce's tweaked version:

```
_($* #,##0.00"*"_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* "-"??_);_(@_)
```

Note that with the above, the asterisk will only appear if you have a postive amount. If you *also* want the asterisk to appear should the amount be negative:

```
_($* #,##0.00"*"_);_($* (#,##0.00)"*";_($* "-"??_);_(@_)
```

If you *only* want an asterisk on a negative amount, use:

```
_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00)"*";_($* "-"??_);_(@_)
```

Comment: [Most excellent](https://media.giphy.com/media/IHBFxgpzIFIFa/giphy.gif). This also has the great advantage over `TEXT()`, since I can still do math with the number(s). :D